# Can we add waiting/delay in azure bicep deployment?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-bicep

Are there any way to add time delay or wait for particular resource deployment in azure bicep (NOT ARM)?
(For example wait until NSG deployment to initiate VNET/Subnet deployment)

Try to add wait. But it is not available !

Answer (score 2):

You can add dependency like this:

```
resource dnsZone 'Microsoft.Network/dnszones@2018-05-01' = {
  name: 'demoeZone1'
  location: 'global'
}

resource otherZone 'Microsoft.Network/dnszones@2018-05-01' = {
  name: 'demoZone2'
  location: 'global'
  dependsOn: [
    dnsZone
  ]
}
```

[MS Document link FYR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/resource-dependencies)

Comment: Actually my issue is when we add depends on until creation of dependencies, code return with failed error. After run-again in 5 - 10 mins it gets success. I think it is due to provision time gap in Azure. I want to add time delay; lets say 10 mins for giving room for creation of dependencies.

Comment: What error you are getting during deployment?

Comment: Please refer sample: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.machinelearningservices/machine-learning-end-to-end-secure/main.bicep

Comment: The issue is sometime provisioning of dependencies takes time in azure. In those cases bicep will return err msg with "some resources are still provisioning". So, in order to mitigate this issue, I wanted to add delay parameter in bicep code to give some wait time until dependencies are getting provisioned.

Comment: In general, AzureRM will start provisioning resources in any order until we provide the hierarchy of resource provisioning. This is common to ARM Templates, Terraform and Azure Bicep. I suggest you to try in a different  location or to try the scripts available in Azure Quick Start Templates.

Comment: I think there is a way of achieving this through Deployment Scripts with ARM but no with bicep. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/add-wait-operation-to-arm-template-deployment/ba-p/2915342